# ogr2ogr unable to kml

Tags: centos6, gdal, ogr

on Centos 6 (vps). I have problem to convert kml to shapefile.

```
[root@vps208386 tmp]# ogr2ogr --version
GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20
```

To check the ogr2ogr, I had converted a shapefile to kml, and works okay

```
ogr2ogr -f 'kml' output.kml output.shp
```

but now, I wanna convert the kml to shapefile, and is not working:

```
ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' output2.shp output.kml
```

as you can see, is the same kml-output, so.. is not a corrupt file.

the result is:

```
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `output.kml' with the following drivers.
  -> `PCIDSK'
  -> `PDF'
  -> `ESRI Shapefile'
  -> `MapInfo File'
  -> `UK .NTF'
  -> `OGR_SDTS'
  -> `S57'
  -> `DGN'
  -> `OGR_VRT'
  -> `REC'
  -> `Memory'
  -> `BNA'
  -> `CSV'
  -> `GML'
  -> `GPX'
  -> `KML'
  -> `GeoJSON'
  -> `OGR_GMT'
  -> `WAsP'
  -> `OpenFileGDB'
  -> `XPlane'
  -> `DXF'
  -> `Geoconcept'
  -> `GeoRSS'
  -> `GPSTrackMaker'
  -> `PGDUMP'
  -> `GPSBabel'
  -> `SUA'
  -> `OpenAir'
  -> `OGR_PDS'
  -> `HTF'
  -> `AeronavFAA'
  -> `EDIGEO'
  -> `SVG'
  -> `Idrisi'
  -> `ARCGEN'
  -> `SEGUKOOA'
  -> `SEGY'
  -> `SXF'
  -> `Selafin'
  -> `JML'
  -> `VDV'
  -> `TIGER'
  -> `AVCBin'
  -> `AVCE00'
```

**but, what is the problem? if I am using the same ogr2ogr OUTPUT**

pd: In my desktop computer (Centos 7) is working okay. in both of them, i had installed ogr2ogr 2.2.3 by using the next:

```
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/etc-data.koordinates.com/gdal-travisci/install-libkml-r864-64bit.tar.gz
tar xzf install-libkml-r864-64bit.tar.gz

#Copy these required files to  /usr/local
sudo cp -r install-libkml/include/* /usr/local/include
sudo cp -r install-libkml/lib/* /usr/local/lib
sudo ldconfig


#download GDAL
wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.2.3/gdal-2.2.3.tar.gz

#Untar
tar xzf gdal-2.2.3.tar.gz
cd gdal-2.2.3

#Compile from source
./configure --with-libkml 
make
make install
```

Comment: I maybe , found the error, always I need to write ```sudo ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' output2.shp output.kml``` but why?

Comment: You may not have full permissions to the location you are trying to write in? My guess was the the KML file was not being written correctly in the first step. Are you able to fully load it in a viewer?